# Как разместить стрелки переключения слайдов на расстоянии от самих слайдов в FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так, чтобы в плагине FancyBox стрелки, отвечающие за переключение слайдов, находились на некотором расстоянии от самого слайда (а не внутри него) и постоянно отображались (а не только при наведении на правую или левую часть слайда). Уже час ковыряю css, но ничего путного не выходит.

Comment: Firebug включи и посмотри где стили находятся

Comment: а как по Вашему я ковырял стили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#fancybox-right span {
    ...
    right: -Xpx;
}
#fancybox-left span {
    ...
    left: -Xpx;
}
```

Про постоянный показ кнопок - на оффсайте fancybox в [FAQ](http://fancybox.net/faq) есть [ответ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/H9dhc0mx6II).

Comment: Если вот так как Вы сказали двигать, то стрелки заходят за #fancy_outer и перестают отображаться.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gridsane/Gk4Qz/

С правой стрелкой сами уж разберетесь думаю